# A markers in PrimeFaces map

Tags: java, markers

I will create a map with primeface gmap.
I have this code in my jsf page as shown in PM show case website:

```
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
      type="text/javascript"></script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
  <h:body>
<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h1>Google Map</h1>
    <p:gmap center="36.890257,30.707417" zoom="13" type="HYBRID" model="#{mapBean.simpleModel}"  style="width:600px;height:400px">  
     </p:gmap>    
</f:view>
```

And my mapBean is :

```
package mesbeans;

import java.io.Serializable;  
import org.primefaces.model.map.DefaultMapModel;  
import org.primefaces.model.map.LatLng;  
import org.primefaces.model.map.MapModel;  
import org.primefaces.model.map.Marker;  

public class MapBean implements Serializable {  

    private MapModel simpleModel;  

    public MapBean() {  
        simpleModel = new DefaultMapModel();  

        //Shared coordinates  
        LatLng coord1 = new LatLng(36.879466, 30.667648);  
        LatLng coord2 = new LatLng(36.883707, 30.689216);  
        LatLng coord3 = new LatLng(36.879703, 30.706707);  
        LatLng coord4 = new LatLng(36.885233, 30.702323);  

        //Basic marker  
        simpleModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord1, "Konyaalti"));  
        simpleModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord2, "Ataturk Parki"));  
        simpleModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord3, "Karaalioglu Parki"));  
        simpleModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord4, "Kaleici"));  
    }  

    public MapModel getSimpleModel() {  
        return simpleModel;  
    }  
}
```

When I run the application, only the map is shown without a marker?

Answer (score 0):

Your MapBean is not recognized in the jsf page. For it to be recognized, use @Named. So your bean should be as below.

```
import org.primefaces.model.map.DefaultMapModel;  
import org.primefaces.model.map.LatLng;  
import org.primefaces.model.map.MapModel;  
import org.primefaces.model.map.Marker;  

import javax.inject.Named

@Named
public class MapBean implements Serializable {  
    private MapModel simpleModel;     
    ......
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create the rinit method and assign the coordinates in it because this method is executed first and loads all the data in the jsf